# Did I over stay, and can I re enter?

Tags: overstaying, 90-180-visa-rules, bulgaria

I need advice and help. I stayed in Sofia for 91 days within 180 days.
I am aware that Bulgaria isn’t really a Schengen country yet. But they seem to be using the 180 days rule.

Further details overstay

Entered on the 29th of October 22 and exited 18th of December 2022( that’s 51 days in the country)

I came back
31 of December 22
Exited 31 of January 23

(That’s 32day)

That’s 83 days

I came back for 7 days.
From the 20th to 27th of April.
Here is where I messed up. From 20 to 27th is 8 days not 7 Days. Counting from 0 rather than 1. But again, not sure if that’s how it done.

I have used schengen 90/180 rule calculator online, and it summed up all my days to 90 days. It also says I can re enter into Bulgarian now because the period of 180days have passed since my first entry. This was on the 29th of October 2022. Is this correct please?
Many thanks
Amanda

Comment: Entry/exit days count. Given you’ve calculated your first two stays correctly, why are you not sure how to calculate your third stay?

Comment: If I calculated correctly, Your first day of the first entry, 29 October was 181 days before you left on 27 April which is why you met the 90 days within 180 and didn't overstay.

Comment: You can enter Bulgaria now, but if you do you can't stay for 90 days.  On April 20th you could have stayed for 58 days.  Because you stayed 8 days, you can now return for up to 50 days.  This is true through May 9th; if you return on any day between May 10th and July 26th, you can return for up to 82 days.  If you return on July 27th or later, you can stay for up to 90 days.

Comment: Thank you so much guys.